# What event should i trigger that works when a customer places an order?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer

I'm new to Magento and the next step I want to learn is to listen to an event. So, I'm trying to find which event should I trigger that works after a customer has placed an order that also carries that order's information, including product SKUs, Order number, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events in Magento 2 are dispatched based on an action performed and it passes data to the observer. Observers are Magento classes that are executed when an event is dispatched. Here, we will make use of this concept to get order data from Magento 2

> “sales_order_place_after” event.

**Step 1: Create events.xml file at app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="place_order_after" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Orderplaceafter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Step 2:  Create Orderplaceafter.php at app/code/Vendor/Extension/Observer/**

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
 
class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $logger;
 
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
 
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            print_r($order->getData());die;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I get most informations I need from a order by using `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`
You get the orderid, customer informations and the item informations.

Just as an addition: I tried multiple observers - most of them have one or two problems:
Either, the informations are not in the database, when the trigger gets triggered
or it gets triggered each time, an order is saved (so it gets triggered multiple times, even after the checkout process is done already).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Magento 2.3.x and 2.4.x and I use this event: `sales_order_save_commit_after`